# Elastic Beanstalk with Elasticache: How to get node address in PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elasticache

I've included a config file as documented here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-environment-resources-elasticache.html

I can see a cache cluster is being created however my PHP app has no way to get the address of that cluster.

Also, it does not look like the ElastiCache Cluster Client for PHP (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PHPAutoDiscoverySetup.html) is being installed automatically, so will appreciate additions to the config file that can install this.

Comment: This sounds like a good question for the [Elastic Beanstalk forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=86).